# jol footprint of HashMap<Integer, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap, footprint, jol

I have a problem with objects footprint understanding:

I'm running the following lines in two cases **A** and **B**

```
out.println(VM.current().details());
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
A:
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        hashMap.put(i, i);
    }
B:
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        hashMap.put(1000 + i, i);
    }

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
pw.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(hashMap).toFootprint());
```

Case A result is:

```
java.util.HashMap@1f89ab83d footprint:
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1      8208      8208   [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
  1872        16     29952   java.lang.Integer
     1        48        48   java.util.HashMap
  1000        32     32000   java.util.HashMap$Node
  2874               70208   (total)
```

Case B result is:

```
java.util.HashMap@1f89ab83d footprint:
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1      8208      8208   [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
  2000        16     32000   java.lang.Integer
     1        48        48   java.util.HashMap
  1000        32     32000   java.util.HashMap$Node
  3002               72256   (total)
```

The difference between A and B is 128 instances of Integer (1872 vs 2000). The first assumption was an `IntegerCache` affects but it does not explain case B in my mind.

**The question**: why these two footprints are different?

details:

```
jol: "org.openjdk.jol:jol-core:0.8"

# Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
# Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
# Using compressed klass with 3-bit shift.
...
# Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
# Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
# Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
```

Comment: I dont see any difference .If you check avg for both the case is same.Do I missing some thing?

Comment: @gatisahu I'd say the average is the memory footprint _per instance_ which naturally should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java indeed has a [cache for `Integer` instances with values between -128 and 127](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) (when using auto-boxing or `Integer.valueOf(int)` directly). Thus `put(i,i)` will use the same instance whereas `put(1000 + i, i)` or even `put(1000 + i, 1000 + i)` won't.

`put(i,i)` will use the cache for values 0 to 127 (i.e. 128 instances) and return the same `Integer` instance in both cases.

`put(1000 + i,i)` will create a new `Integer` instance for the key but use the cache for values 0 to 127 (i.e. 128 instances)

`put(1000 + i, 1000 + i)` will create new `Integer` instances for both the key and the value even though they have the same numerical value. Thus if you'd do that you should see 128 additional `Integer` instance be created.